# Unable to add item to cart on custom Big Cartel build

Tags: liquid, bigcartel

I built a custom Big Cartel theme using Dugway and everything is working fine locally, but when I copy and paste the files into "Customize Design" in my store's dashboard, I see a liquid error on the /product page.

This may or may not be causing the following issue:

When I click 'add to cart' from the /product page, it redirects me to the "Your cart is empty" message. Everything work fine locally. I'm relying on the cart.js.coffee file included in the Dugway build for cart interaction.

Here's my layout.html. When I remove it, the liquid error goes away, but that's probably because all references to the javascript goes away...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ store.name }} &mdash; {{ page.name }}</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="{{ page.meta_description }}">
        <meta name="keywords" content="{{ page.meta_keywords }}">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link href="{{ theme | theme_css_url }}" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{ 'api' | theme_js_url }}"></script>
        <script src="http://fuzzco.com/wp-content/assets/advice-dice/javascripts/theme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{ theme | theme_js_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://use.typekit.net/cev3aiy.js"></script>
        <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
        {{ head_content }}
    </head>
    <body id="{{ page.permalink }}" class="{{ page.category }}">
        <div id="{{ page.name }}"></div>
        <div id="{{ page.permalink }}">
            <header>
                <nav class="global-nav">
                    <div class="row no-margin">
                        <div class="global-nav-left">
                            <a href="/">
                                <img class="global-nav-logo" src="http://fuzzco.com/wp-content/assets/advice-dice/images/ad-logo.svg">
                                <p class="global-nav-text" id="global-nav-text_advice-dice">Advice Dice</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="global-nav-right">
                                <p class="top-right-nav-wrapper">
                                    <a href="/cart" class="cart-icon">
                                        {% for item in cart.items %}

                                            cart <span id="cart-amount">({{cart.item_count}})</span>

                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="/product/test-dice">
                                        <span class="global-nav-text" id="global-nav-top-right">shop</span>
                                    </a>
                                </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <div class="main-content">

              {{ page_content }}

            </div>
            <footer class="global-footer">
                <nav class="global-nav">
                    <div class="row no-margin">
                        <div class="global-nav-left">
                            <a href="/try-it">
                                <p class="global-nav-text" id="global-nav-bottom-left">try it!</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="global-nav-right">
                            <a href="/about">
                                <p class="global-nav-text" id="global-nav-bottom-right">about</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My store is advicedice.bigcartel.com. I'm not sure what other code will be beneficial because I'm not sure where it's coming from, so if anyone has an idea off the bat or has experienced this before I would love to start digging in. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Your code seems fine to me - it might have something to do with the fact that your product is marked as 'Sold out' ? Are you able to add the item to your cart after setting it to 'Active' ?

Comment: Hey Nick -- that doesn't seem to be the issue. I had switched it over to "Sold Out" just to see if I could get it to react differently, and I forgot to switch it back over to 'active.' Still trying to diagnose what's happening here, but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness' sake, the issue has been resolved - it was caused by a bug related to the quantity input field.